# How to display an array of HTML elements in a Rails view (as HTML, not strings) while using join

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object called `r` that has an attribute `subjects` due to a many-to-many relationship. I am trying to print out the `subjects` of `r` as links using `link_to` helper and joining them together using `join`. Here's my code:

```
<%= r.subjects.map { |s| link_to  s.name, subject_path(s) } .join "," %>
```

However, I get HTML `anchor` elements as strings, not as HTML. I would like to get actual HTML anchor elements.

Comment: you need to call `html_safe` on each string to make it "HTML enabled", but beware: seeing your code, if the name of a subject contains HTML code, it will be treated as HTML, so potential injection possible here!

Comment: @MrYoshiji The name of a subject is just a string. Will I have a potential injection issue here?

Comment: Yes, if the name of the subject is `/><b>This is bold</b>` or something like that, then  it will "interpret" the HTML in there

Comment: @MrYoshiji how can I resolve this injection threat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead `join`, you can take advantage of [`ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper#safe_join`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-safe_join). And in that result, invoke [`String#html_safe`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe):

```
<%= safe_join(r.subjects.map { |s| link_to  s.name, subject_path(s) }, ',').html_safe %>
```

Comment: I tried using `html_safe` inside the `map` function (on each element), but didn't get HTML anchor elements. Do you know why that didn't work?

Comment: Isn't it because `html_safe` is a String objects method, and `link_to` is an `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer` object?

Comment: This is what I tried:
`<%= r.subjects.map { |s| (link_to  s.name, subject_path(s)).html_safe } .join "," %>`

Comment: Remove the `join`, and wrap that in a `safe_join`, e.g: `<%= safe_join(r.subjects.map { |s| (link_to s.name, subject_path(s)).html_safe }, ',') %>`.